# Can I change a theme and then sell it?

Tags: licensing, legal, apache-license

I am thinking of starting with the "Start Bootstrap" theme from Bootstrap and I want to change it and add stuff, new pages to work with Wordpress and then put it up for sale.

http://startbootstrap.com/template-overviews/creative/

Under the Apache License Version 2.0 can I change (back-end and front-end) a theme and then sell it? Can I take credit for my work? And if not then what I am allowed to do under this policy?

Comment: did you check prior questions here before asking? eg, [How can I compare and contrast open source licenses?](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/q/120308/31260) and [Is there a chart for helping me decide between open-source licenses?](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/q/105344/31260)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it asks for very specific legal advice that we cannot provide. Please read [What types of legal questions are on-topic here?](http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/q/1655/88986) and [When is a software licensing question on topic?](http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/q/7265/88986)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Apache License Version 2.0 is an Open Source license. This means that you can take the material under the Apache license, make changes to it and re-distribute the changed version.

The restrictions that you have are

- The original startbootstrap theme must remain under the Apache License Version 2.0
- You are not allowed to remove or change the copyright or license notices in the files that you didn't create yourself

You are permitted to make changes and even to provide your changed theme under a proprietary license and ask money for it.